# Are there any unit vector dot product identites?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, systems-of-equations

Given 3d unit vectors $\hat{r}_1,\hat{r}_2,\hat{r}_3,\hat{r}_4$,  (i.e. where  $\hat{r}_i\cdot \hat{r}_i=1$ and $\hat{r}_i \in \mathcal{R}^3$) are there any identities for tying together their dot products $\hat{r}_i\cdot \hat{r}_j$?

For example, something like $\hat{r}_1\cdot\hat{r}_2+\hat{r}_2\cdot\hat{r}_3 = \hat{r}_1\cdot\hat{r}_3$?  (NOT true)

**Context:** I'm working on an under determined system of equations involving dot products between 4 or more unknown unit vectors. My gut feeling is I'm missing something in the geometry that would give me the last piece of the puzzle. **Edit:** I removed most of the context because it just distracted from the question and the answer (given below, based on Daniel's comment).

Comment: I think you might be better off not trying to hide your context so much.  Provide more!

Comment: Is $\hat r_5$ a unit vector? If so, $\hat r_4\cdot\hat r_5=1$ implies $\hat r_4=\hat r_5$.

Comment: You're right, that was a mistake

Comment: equations 2 and 4 can be simplified since $r_4\cdot r_3=0$ and $r_5\cdot r_3=0$.

Comment: Is number $3$ in first equation correct?

Comment: also, if $\hat{r}_4$ and $\hat{r}_5$ are given and one is not multiple of the other, then $\hat{r}_3$ can be found. Use the cross product, since $\hat{r}_3$ is a normal to plane generated by $\hat{r}_4$ and $\hat{r}_5$. Now that you changed the equations, not sure if this comment makes sense.

Comment: Yes. Just a constant. Should also be in the 3rd. I'll fix that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm updating it as I think it through better. r3 is one thing I know (sort of defines the coordinate system. But if I know r4, I also know r5.

Comment: And no 3 in fifth equation?

Comment: Yea... that was another error. I swear I looked them over several times first. I rearranged them a bit to make the symmetries a little more apparent.

Comment: Since the four vectors are linearly dependent, that would imply the Gramian determinant is zero.

Comment: Its possible for r1=r2=r3=r4=r5. In general r1, r2 and r3 can each be anything. r4 and r5 are determined by the other three and additional information not given here.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I missread your comment (read independent instead of dependent) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant of the [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) is zero if the vectors are linearly dependent. Since any combination of 4 or more vectors in $\mathcal{R}^3$ are guaranteed to be linearly dependent, each such combination can give me an equation to work with.

For example, for unit vectors $\hat{r}_1,\hat{r}_2,\hat{r}_3, \hat{r}_4$ the Gramian matrix is:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & \hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_2 & \hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_3 & \hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_4 \\
 \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_1 & 1 & \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_3 & \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_4 \\
 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_1 & \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_2 & 1 & \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_4 \\
 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_1 & \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_2 & \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_3 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

And setting the determinant to 0 gives:

$$
0=-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_2 \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_1+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_3 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_2
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_1+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_2
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_1-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_3 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_2
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_1-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_2 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_3
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_1+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_2 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_3
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_1-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_3 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_1+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_2
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_3 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_1-\hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_3
   \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_2-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_1+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_2
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_1+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_3
   \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_2 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_1-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_3 \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_4
   \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_2 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_1+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_3 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_4
   \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_1-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_2 \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_3 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_4
   \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_1-\hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_2-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_4
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_3 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_1 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_2+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_3
   \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_1 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_2+\hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_3
   \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_2+\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_1
   \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_3-\hat{r}_1.\hat{r}_2 \hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_1
   \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_3+\hat{r}_2.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_2
   \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_3-\hat{r}_3.\hat{r}_4 \hat{r}_4.\hat{r}_3+1
$$

Thanks to Daniel for pointing out this property in the comments. I think this property captures exactly what I was intuitively grasping for.

FWIW doing this on Mathematica was fairly easy:

```
g=Outer[Dot,{r1,r2,r3,r4},{r1,r2,r3,r4}]; g //MatrixForm
reps = {r1.r1->1, r2.r2->1, r3.r3->1,r4.r4->1,r5.r5->1, r1->Subscript[ OverHat[r],1], r2->Subscript[ OverHat[r],2], r3->Subscript[ OverHat[r],3], r4->Subscript[ OverHat[r],4], r5->Subscript[ OverHat[r],5]}
Det[g]/.reps
%//TeXForm
g  /.reps //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```